# how to implement add to cart functionality on custom module

Tags: php, magento

I am new in magento. I have made a custom module of price calculator in which a user enter the height and width of a product and it gets its price. I want to implement add to cart functionality so that height,width and price goes to cart. But i don't know the code and syntax to implement it.

Cart functionality is already installed on my project.

This is controller

```
    class Test_Mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action 
{
    public function indexAction() 
    { 
         $this->loadLayout(); 
         $this->renderLayout(); 
    }

    public function calculateAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $printdata = $request->getPost();

        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) 
         {
             $obj = Mage::getModel("test_mymodule/results");

             $show_results = $obj->showshuttersprice($printdata['width'],$printdata['height']);

         }



         Mage::register('data', $show_results);// In the Controller

         Mage::register('width', $printdata['width']);// In the Controller

         Mage::register('height', $printdata['height']);// In the Controller


            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();           

    } 
}
```

This is my view in which i want to implement add to cart

```
<h6 align="center">Price Results for <?php echo $width; ?> mm by <?php echo $height; ?> mm Domestic Rollershutter</h6>
     <table border="1" align="center" width="100%" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
           <tr>
               <td>Price</td> <td><?php echo "$"." ".$data; ?></td>
           </tr>

       </table>      



<?php
}
?>
<br />
<a href ="">Add to cart</a>
```

Any body Please help me

Answer (score 2):

For quick fix, you can try to create the add to cart url something like this.

```
<a href ="http://www.yourdomain.com/checkout/cart/add?product=68&qty=1">Add to cart</a>
```

replace product value with your dynamic product id so that it can add

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<a href ="">Add to cart</a>`, you can try:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart v-center" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```